# The method showSaveDialog(Component) in the type JFileChooser is not applicable for ()

Tags: java, swing

I want to initialize a frame, with a saveDialog, however when using this `chooser.showSaveDialog(this);` I get an error:

```
public void initialize() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Menu
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
    menu.add(new AbstractAction("Make Image") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser  = new JFileChooser();
            int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
            if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                writeJPEGImage(file);
            }
        }});

    JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(menu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);


    content.add(tree);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Error:**

> The method showSaveDialog(Component) in the type JFileChooser is not
>   applicable for the arguments ()

I know that this methods usually gets a Component, but I do not have any in my class, cause I am loading it in this method.

Any recommendations how to fix that?

I appreciate your answer!

**PS.:** `new Test()` does work, but I have to give it the current component!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use frame variable you have created as the parameter or also content variable.

```
int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
```

or

```
int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(content);
```

Also you have to define them final to be able to access them from your anonymous class:

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

or

```
final Container content = frame.getContentPane();
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument should be the parent component/window it is in, the JFrame most like. However `this` refers to an anonymous child class of AbstractAction.

Either use null, or use a qualified `this` using your classes name, if that code is in the frame class:

```
int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(MyFrame.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this context...

```
new AbstractAction("Make Image") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
```

`this` refers to the instance of `AbstractAction`.

Instead, you most likely want to use the parent component reference.

```
int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
```

Since you have create the `frame` as a local variable, you will need to make it `final`

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```